# Unable to run specs by using drivers, getting error for video-reporter plugin is not installed

Tags: javascript, npm, automated-tests, webdriver-io

Unable to run specs by using drivers, getting the following Error message even if I followed documentation and even all plugins are installed.

Here's the dependencies from `wdio.conf.ts`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@wdio/allure-reporter": "^8.27.2",
    "@wdio/cli": "^8.27.2",
    "@wdio/junit-reporter": "^8.27.2",
    "@wdio/local-runner": "^8.27.2",
    "@wdio/mocha-framework": "^8.27.2",
    "@wdio/spec-reporter": "^8.27.2",
    "allure-commandline": "^2.25.0",
    "chromedriver": "^120.0.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.2",
    "typescript": "^5.3.3",
    "wdio-chromedriver-service": "^8.1.1",
    "wdio-edgedriver-service": "^3.0.3",
    "wdio-video-reporter": "^5.1.0"
  }
```

And here's the log

```
Execution of 1 workers started at 2024-01-16T06:24:25.936Z

2024-01-16T06:24:25.951Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onPrepare hook
2024-01-16T06:24:25.952Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser driver for: chrome@stable
2024-01-16T06:24:25.953Z INFO @wdio/utils: Setting up browser binaries for: chrome@stable
2024-01-16T06:24:26.007Z INFO webdriver: Downloading Chromedriver v120.0.6099.216
2024-01-16T06:24:26.403Z WARN webdriver: Chromedriver v120.0.6099.216 don't exist, trying to find known good version...
2024-01-16T06:24:27.683Z INFO webdriver: Download of Chromedriver v120.0.6099.109 was successful
2024-01-16T06:24:27.688Z INFO @wdio/cli:launcher: Run onWorkerStart hook
2024-01-16T06:24:27.689Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Start worker 0-0 with arg: run,./wdio.conf.ts,--suite,revisiquantity
[0-0] 2024-01-16T06:24:28.444Z INFO @wdio/local-runner: Run worker command: run
[0-0] 2024-01-16T06:24:29.439Z ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: Error: Couldn't find plugin "video" reporter, neither as wdio scoped package "@wdio/video-reporter" nor as community package "wdio-video-reporter". Please make sure you have it installed!
```

I already tried to update using `npx npm-check-updates -u` and re-install the dependencies but still error. And spesifically reinstalled `wdio-video-reporter` with command-line `npm install wdio-video-reporter --save-dev` but still getting error.